# Google cloud ml cannot deploy graph for prediction api

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

Has anybody tried exporting tensorflow model built on local machine and use google cloud ml prediction API uploading this model?

I am trying to build a graph using slightly modified version of retraining example given in [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/12/how-to-train-and-classify-images-using-google-cloud-machine-learning-and-cloud-dataflow) blog on my local machine and upload exported model checkpoints directly to cloud ml for prediction. However it throws an error saying:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ml.predict) HTTP request failed. Response: {                                     
  "error": {                                                                                         
    "code": 503,                                                                                     
    "message": "Field: name Error: Online prediction service is unavailable for this version. Please 
try again in around 60 seconds.",                                                                    
    "status": "UNAVAILABLE",                                                                         
    "details": [                                                                                     
      {                                                                                              
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",                                        
        "fieldViolations": [                                                                         
          {                                                                                          
            "field": "name",                                                                         
            "description": "Online prediction service is unavailable for this version. Please try aga
in in around 60 seconds."                                                                            
          }                                                                                          
        ]                                                                                            
      }                                                                                              
    ]                                                                                                
  }                                                                                                  
}
```

When for debugging, I try to predict locally with same graph and same example using command `gcloud beta ml local predict`, it gives error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ml.local.predict) WARNING:root:Couldn't find python-snappy so the implementation 
of _TFRecordUtil._masked_crc32c is not as fast as it could be.                                       
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                   
  File "lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/ml/local_predict.py", line 112, in <module>                   
    main()                                                                                           
  File "lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/ml/local_predict.py", line 107, in main                       
    instances=instances)                                                                             
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ml/prediction/_prediction_lib.py", line
 731, in local_predict                                                                               
    client = SessionClient(*load_model(model_dir))                                                   
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ml/prediction/_prediction_lib.py", line
 339, in load_model                                                                                  
    model_path)                                                                                      
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ml/session_bundle/_session_bundle.py", 
line 153, in load_session_bundle_from_path                                                           
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_graph_def)                                               
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1708, in 
import_meta_graph                                                                                    
    return _import_meta_graph_def(meta_graph_or_file, clear_devices)                                 
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1598, in 
_import_meta_graph_def                                                                               
    input_graph_def, name="", producer_op_list=producer_op_list)                                     
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 258, 
in import_graph_def                                                                                  
    op_def = op_dict[node.op]                                                                        
KeyError: u'TensorArrayV2'
```

It seems that it cannot import all the graph elements from model. I have exported model using this command:

```
saver.export_meta_graph(filename=os.path.join("/trainer/", 'export.meta'))
saver.save(sess, os.path.join("/trainer/", 'export'), write_meta_graph=False)
```

Comment: gcloud beta ml local predict uses the version of TensorFlow on your machine. What version of TF did you use to train the model and what version do you have installed on your machine?

Comment: @rhaertel80 Local version installed is: 0.11.0

Comment: We've introduced specific runtime versions into CloudML. Do you mind trying again and letting us know what happens?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: @Adam sorry I setup workflow on bare instances so did not try it on CloudML again. I will give it a try and let you know.